# How to match a regular expression to a text file?

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to read from a file as text by `data=fileread('channelresult')` function. Then the `data` is used for regular expression matching. The `channelresult` file content is:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-0.10   sec  9.24 MBytes   774 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   0.10-0.20   sec  14.8 MBytes  1.24 Gbits/sec                  
[  4]   0.20-0.30   sec  15.0 MBytes  1.27 Gbits/sec                  
[  4]   0.30-0.40   sec  17.6 MBytes  1.48 Gbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.74 GBytes  1.49 Gbits/sec  1005             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.74 GBytes  1.49 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

The regular expression I use is

```
pattern=number_str+'\s+sec\s+'+number_str+'\s+\w+\s+'+number_str+'\s+(\w)\w+/\w+\s+(\d+)\s+'+number_str+'\s(\w)'
```

And `number_str='(\d*\.\d+|\d+)'`. When I use `out = regexp(data,pattern,'match')` the variable `out` does not contain anything. It's a 0 by 0 cell array.

Comment: Try `\[[^][]*]\s+(\d*\.?\d+-\d*\.?\d+)\s+sec\s+(\d*\.?\d+)\s+\w+\s+(\d*\.?\d+)\s+(\w)\w+/\w+`, see https://regex101.com/r/jikysb/1

Comment: As Wiktor suggests, regex101,com is a great resource for these kind of things.